# Installing Cement Board 16 inches on center

Tags: framing, cement-board

I'm going to be using cement board for the walls of my walk-in shower. My shower is framed 16 inches on center.

It appears that most cement board measures 5 ft. x 3 ft.

Does this mean I'm going to have to cut pretty much every single piece of cement board down to a dimension that properly fits the 16 inches on center framing?

Comment: How big is your shower?

Comment: 79 in. x 44in. It's a pretty big one.

Comment: I recently built a shower and used [DensShield](http://www.buildgp.com/densshield-tilebacker-board) and it's much easier to cut than cement board.  It's embedded with fiberglass so wear a mask if you use it.

Comment: +1 on DensShield. use it, love it. You need to seal the seams with fiberglass tape and membrane. Also seal screw penetrations if they break the surface.

Comment: These boards fit regular sized showers well, which is probably they are that size

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You're only really talking about making three more cuts than you would if you were working with sheets that had lengths of say 64". Your runs are only two sheets long, and you'd have had to cut one sheet for each row anyway. The short wall doesn't have this problem.

You can get 32" cementboard, which you could run vertically (assuming manufacturer approval).

Comment: So then the answer to my question is yes? It's not really the amount of cuts I'm worried about, it just seems like I'd be wasting a lot of product having to cut each board. I wasn't sure if there was a different pattern or way of laying it out that would work without having to cut each one. Also, doesn't look like i have the 32" available at my local hardware stores.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add a few boards for extra framing...  Probably 3/4 of the showers I do I put up at least two three framing boards - both vertical and horizontal.  Whether bath or shower make sure you have a good amount of wood where door or curtain rod would be installed.

Comment: Too late now to install any extra boards as the plumbing has already been done. But for future reference, where do you usually decide to add them?

Comment: You want some crosses on cement boards.  I want to be able to drill in all the way around a cement board - the middle not as concerned.  This is due to the boards becoming offset from the framing due to their stiffness.  And like I said in answer I would suggest putting in 3+ studs where you would put a door or curtain rods.